# Titanium VideoPlayer bug: iOS 5 (or iPhone 4s with iOS 5)

Tags: ios5, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I have been developing an app that supports streaming video and audio, among other things. I've gotten everything to work perfectly on my iPhone 3S with iOS 4 as well as my Android device. Tonight, I deployed the app to my new iPhone 4S with iOS5 and now the VideoPlayer will not exit when I click on the "done" button on the top-left of the title bar! The video is playing full screen and I cannot get back to any of my application screens. Is this a known bug?

Here is my code for the view for review or to reproduce:

```
var contentURL = 'http://streaming.alburhan.tv/Video/GetURL/ME';
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;
win.orientationModes = [Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT, Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT];

var videoURL = "";
getURL:);

function getURL() {
    var header, responseText;
    //alert('Retrieving from ' + contentURL);
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

    xhr.timeout = 15000;
    xhr.onload = function() {
        try {
            //alert('Connecting...');
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            Ti.API.info(this.status);
            if(this.status == 200) {
                Ti.API.info('Response ' + this.responseText);
                responseText = this.responseText;
            } else {
                Ti.API.info:'Status ' + this.status:;
                Ti.API.info('Response ' + this.responseText:;
            }
            //alert:responseText);
            if :responseText            //alert:evaluated.URL);
                videoURL = evaluated.URL;

                var activeMovie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer:{
                    contentURL: videoURL,
                    backgroundColor:'#111',
                    //movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_DEFAULT,
                    //scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_FILL
                    movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_FULLSCREEN,
                    scalingMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SCALING_ASPECT_FIT,
                    sourceType:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_SOURCE_TYPE_STREAMING
                }:;

                if (parseFloat(Titanium.Platform.version) >= 3.2)
                {
                    win.add(activeMovie);
                }

                var windowClosed = false;

                activeMovie.addEventListener('complete',function()
                {
                    if :!windowClosed)
                    {
                        //Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog:{title:'Movie', message:'Completed!'}:.show();
                    }
                    win.close:);
                }:;

                activeMovie.fullscreen = true;
                activeMovie.play:);

                win.addEventListener('close', function() 
                {
                    if (!windowClosed)
                    {
                        windowClosed = true;
                        //alert:"Window closed":;
                        activeMovie.stop();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Could not load video data from the server. Please try again later.');
            }
        }
        catch(E){
            alert('There was an error retrieving stream data from the server: ' + E);
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('Could not connect to the server in order to retrieve stream data: ' + e.error);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", contentURL);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've fixed the issue. For anyone following this issue or who runs into it in the future, this is what I ended up doing/changing to get it to function properly on iOS 5:

`movieControlMode:Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_EMBEDDED`

Also, I added the following event listeners:

```
activeMovie.addEventListener('complete', function() {
                    //alert('completed');
                    if (!windowClosed) {
                        activeMovie.fullscreen = true;
                        activeMovie.stop();
                        activeMovie.release();
                        windowClosed = true;
                        win.close();
                    }
                });

                activeMovie.addEventListener('fullscreen', function(e) { // When fullscreen status is changed.
                    if (!e.entering) { // User pressed 'done' or video finished.
                        activeMovie.fullscreen = true;
                        activeMovie.stop();
                        activeMovie.release();
                        windowClosed = true;
                        win.remove(activeMovie);
                        win.close();
                    }
                });
```

Why I had to make these changes (especially the `movieControlMode`) to get it working properly on iOS 5 is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
activeMovie.fullscreen = true;
```

to this:

```
activeMovie.fullscreen = false;
```

I know, it makes no sense. Welcome to Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Technically, that fixes the issue, but I want the movie to be full screen. Besides, when it is not full screen, there's yet another bug. This is how to reproduce it:

When playing the video, rotate the screen so it is in landscape mode. Then, click the double arrows that causes the movie to scale larger. What happens then is that the top status bar drops about 150 pixels or so, leaving a gap at the top of the screen and overlaying part of the top of the video. The strange thing is, in iOS 4, full screen exits fine when I click the "done" button. Any suggestions?